# Find the antiderivative of : $f(x)= \left(1+x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{m}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to find the antiderivative of the following function:

> $$f(x)= \left(1+x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{m}}$$

where $m$ is an integer constant.

Please could you help me in finding how could I find the primitive of this function? Is there any particular technique concerning this types of functions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Vasya for the antiderivative? OP is essentially asking for an "indefinite integral."

Comment: It is well known https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Differential_binomial

Comment: Mathematica tells me that the antiderivative is the [Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). I suppose you could find this by calculating the Maclauren series of f(x) and integrating term-by-term.

Comment: Why is $m$ restricted to be an integer?  I don’t think that that is necessary.

Comment: Let $a=\frac1m$